# FindSpanningTree not working properly on directed graph with negative weights

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

The code:

```
FindSpanningTree[
 Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3,
    3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1}, 
  EdgeWeight -> {-1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3}]]
```

will return three disconnected points. Adding a constant offset to make all weights positive fixes the problem. Note that the graph is directed.

Comment: Please report bugs to Wolfram Support.

Comment: (For those who are testing this in older versions, it's good to be aware that before M12.2, FindSpanningTree returned completely wrong results on _weighted and directed_ graphs. This was fixed in 12.2.)